# Why is my 14 yr old listed as adult with my name on our account family sharing

Tags: ios, apple-id, family-sharing

I opened up find my iPhone account between myself my daughter 15yrs old and son 14 yrs old. We all previously had our Apple ID numbers. I'm listed as organizer I'm 38 yrs old. My son is listed under adult and with my name MICHELLE BANCROFT not his own. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

First log in to [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com) and update his birthday, name etc.

Second, log in to the organizer account and change the role for all accounts that are incorrect. If this is correct and still shows Adult, you can kick him from Family Sharing then invite him again as a non-adult. :) If you save their real birthdays, they will be picked up as minors/teenagers by their age (-18).

Check [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6543361?tstart=0), for interest sake. :P

> [Family Sharing and Apple ID for your child](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT201084)

At the bottom of Apple's support articles, there's a contact us link to get personalized support or you can start at http://apple.com/support